# Como capturar o resultado de uma execução do doctrine2?

Tags: php, doctrine, doctrine-2

Estou implementado doctrine em um projeto, porém estou com uma duvida quanto a inserção, atualização e remoção de dados.
Quando executo o seguinte comando por exemplo:

```
$companyName = $entityManager->getRepository("Admin\\Module\\Configuration\\Entity\\Config")->findOneBy(array("type"=>"company_name")); 
$companyName->setValue($POST["companyName"]); 
$entityManager->persist($companyName);
$entityManager->flush();
```

Como posso capturar o resultado do doctrine para saber se ele realmente deu o persist e também executou o flush com sucesso? No caso não consegui pegar o retorno dele ainda. Tentei com try catch, mas a Exception sempre volta vazia.

Gostaria de saber se existe algo parecido ao affected_rows do mysqli para usar no doctrine

Answer (score 1):

A classe `EntityManager` do Doctrine, que usa as classes que implementam a interface `Connection` (ou seja, as classes `PDOConnection`, `DB2Connection`, `MysqliConnection`, `OCI8Connection` e `SQLSrvConnection`) afim de efetuar a conexão com os bancos de dados, não aproveita a contagem de linhas modificadas (ou retornadas) por uma query.

O que dá pra fazer é tentar capturar os erros por meio do bloco `try` / `catch` ou verificar diretamente na conexão se houve algum erro usando os métodos:

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->errorCode()
```

ou

```
$entityManager->getConnection()->errorInfo()
```

Comment: Vale a pena perguntar se existe uma extensão ou api de terceiros que implementa essa contagem no doctrine?

Comment: Se o valor de linhas afetadas não é exposto acredito que seja por algum bom motivo, ou porque você pode conseguir o valor de outra maneira (por exemplo, o tamanho do seu resultset inicial). Tem algum caso que você precisa muito dessa contagem?

Comment: é relativo na verdade, estou fazendo inserções em ajax e queria dar a resposta contendo o número de linhas afetadas e também queria usar para validar o retorno em alguns casos. Mas na maioria é mais por questão didática mesmo, é sempre bom saber até onde se estendem as possibilidades de uma ferramenta

Answer (score 0):

Vc pode ligar o log SQL do Doctrine na aplicação e verificar no banco se os registros estão lá. Caso o flush não tenha sido feito os registros não aparecerão no banco.
Se estiver usando Doctrine com Symfony, no config.yml principal da aplicação, coloque a chave doctrine: dbal: logging: para true e todos os sqls gerados pelo Doctrine serão logados no log principal da aplicação.

Comment: Não estou usando symfony na aplicação e ficar checando os logs não me parece a forma mais correta de fazer essa verificação ou captura. Um exemplo simples é quando usamos o mysqli e podemos capturar o affected_rows na query, coisa que não encontrei no doctrine ainda. e basicamente é isso que eu precisaria.

Answer (score 0):

```
$companyName = $entityManager->getRepository("Admin\\Module\\Configuration\\Entity\\Config")

->findOneBy(array("type"=>"company_name")); 

$companyName->setValue($POST["companyName"]); 

$entityManager->persist($companyName);

$entityManager->flush();

var_dump($companyName);
```

Vai imprimir um objeto com os dados capturados do banco, inclusive o id. Pode fazer que da certo.